# Как сделать фильтр по свойствам и обработать на php

Tags: php, html

Здравствуйте! не как не могу понят как сделать фильтр по свойствам в интернет магазине делаю так:

Размер

```
<input type="checkbox" name="value[20509][28315]" value="">
<input type="checkbox" name="value[20509][28316]" value="">
```

1. [20509] = Размер [28315] = m
2. [20509] = Размер [28316] = l

Стиль

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="value[412][800000067]" value="">
    <input type="checkbox" name="value[412][1000003]" value="">
```

1. [412] = Стиль [28315] = Ретро
2. [412] = Стиль [28316] = Случайный

---

как перебрать это что бы вышло так:

```
<Configurator Pid="20509" Vid="28315"/>
<Configurator Pid="20509" Vid="28316"/>
<Configurator Pid="412" Vid="800000067"/>
<Configurator Pid="412" Vid="1000003"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($_POST['value'] as $k => $v) {
    foreach ($v as $value) {
        echo '<Configurator Pid="' . $k . '" Vid="' . $v . '"/>';
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо заработало вот так `foreach ($_GET['value'] as $k => $v) {
     foreach ($v as $value => $val) {
       echo '<Configurator Pid="' . $k . '" Vid="' . $value . '"/>';
     }
 }` а я совсем и забыл про ключ и значения